# Laravel: Different composer.json files for dev and production

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I need to have 2 different `composer.json` files for `dev` and `production` because I am developing vendor packages (locally) and would like to keep my vendor packages symlinked on dev environment because it's much easier to maintain.

The `composer.json` files contain:

- For development, it has symlinked repositories by path.
- For production, it has private repositories on github.

**NOTE**: The vendor packages are in `require`, and not `require-dev`... So an `composer update --no-dev` will not work.

How could I set this up?

Usually, the `.env` file is where you set different environment variables. Is there a way to set a `COMPOSER_PATH` variable that would point to the 2 different files on prod or dev?

Comment: Assuming your `composer.json` is checked in, maybe use a different branch in dev?

Comment: You may end up with different dependencies installed on dev environment than on production. You will lose main advantage of `composer.lock`.

Comment: Good idea @adam, thx. @rob006, I don't see any major disadvantages: prod will use `composer.lock` and dev `composer-testing.lock`. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: You can continue to use the same lock. The only difference in the lock on dev will be the first party(your) vendor packages in development. The point of the lock is to keep third party vendor packages in check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [environment variables](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables) to have more than one composer files like `composer.json` and `composer-testing.json` and use it in a terminal with:

```
COMPOSER=composer-testing.json php composer.phar install
```